# Discord bot unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, bots

I have read up on the error but I can't seem to find what's wrong with this code for my discord bot:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require('./alphatoken.json');

client.on("ready?", () => {
  console.log("I am ready!");
});

client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith("bing")) {
    message.channel.send("bong!");
  }

client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith("ping")) {
    message.channel.send("pong!");
  }
});

  client.login('M-bot-token');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing `});` in your second `client.on`, so your listener never gets closed properly.

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith("bing")) {
    message.channel.send("bong!");
  }
});
```

As an extra note, you could also just use one listener for your `message`, ie.

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith("bing")) {
    message.channel.send("bong!");
  }
  if (message.content.startsWith("ping")) {
    message.channel.send("pong!");
  }
});
```